# How to Rise an event for ProgressBar (Beginner)

Tags: c#

I would like to rise an event when ProgressBar at 0 or at 100, however despite my efforts I haven't found such event in ProgressBar Events for Value Property and I wonder how can I implement such event by myself?

Where do I declare such event?

Comment: Since you have to manually set the progress's value, don't you know when it 0 and 100?

Comment: Well I might know but its about rising an event in application that will point to a method that will do some work when its 0 or 100.

Comment: Hey! Three years too late, but if anyone is trying to do this in UWP with a progress bar I have found a solution! You can implement a storyboard to drive the animation of your progress bar by setting the Storyboard.TargetName to the name of your progress bar and then calling the Completed event. To do both 0 and 100, you would have to have two animations, but on completion, you could raise an event. Hopefully this work around will help you too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProgressBar` is just an `indicator`, so it doesn't support some `ValueChanged` event. However you can customize it to support such an event and other similar event as you want:

```
    public class CustomProgressBar : ProgressBar
    {
        public event EventHandler ReachedMinimum;
        public event EventHandler ReachedMaximum;
        public event EventHandler ValueChanged;            
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == 0x402)//PBM_SETPOS = WM_USER + 2
            {     
               EventHandler handler = ValueChanged;
               if(handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
               handler = ReachedMinimum;                    
               if (Value == Minimum && handler!=null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
               handler = ReachedMaximum;
               if (Value == Maximum && handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            } 
        }
    }
    //Use it
    customProgressBar1.ReachedMaximum += (s,e) => {
          MessageBox.Show("Reached maximum!");
    };
    //... the same for other events
```

Comment: Do mention the kind of problem the *new* keyword can cause.  Like the Increment() and PerformStep() methods will not raise the event.  Nor does re-assigning the Maximum and Minimum properties btw.

Comment: @HansPassant as I understand the problem with `new` keyword may be that when we cast the `CustomProgressBar` to `ProgressBar` and we can access the `base.Value`? That problem seems to also happen with `override`, Could you tell me some situation in which `new` keyword causes some problem? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but that's not the only problem.  The Increment and PerformStep methods update the shadowed Value property, not the new one.  Okay if he knows about it, a day of his life lost when he doesn't.

Comment: If you want to create a progress bar that truly handles this well you should encapsulate `ProgressBar`, not inherit from it, so that you can properly control access to what is needed.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for pointing out the problem. I updated the answer with catching the message `PBM_SETPOS` instead, it works smoothly now.

Comment: Reading from the comments it looks like an answer, tho my current level is not capable to grasp fully what you have provided as answer  but if you have checked it and it work then I'll mark it as answer and will go to fill gaps in understanding :) Thanks for help everyone.